# How can I control an Ubuntu computer from another Ubuntu computer through the internet?

Tags: remote-access

I'd like to know how to control another Ubuntu OS from my personal computer with Ubuntu, like remote access through the internet.

There is any native software to perform this task? Or a built-in software in Ubuntu? If it's more than one, could you please list it?

Thanks.

Comment: With remote access you mean access that is not a LAN, right?

Comment: Remote access through internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've personally found that installing and using **[TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/)** (*although it actually works under a custom version of **Wine***) is the most straight-forward solution for remote access/control.

Comment: There is no need to use Wine as there is a version for Ubuntu. Also thanks for the answer.

Comment: To clarify further, it is not installed under $HOME/.wine but it is actually installed under /opt/teamviewer/teamviewer/$VERSION/wine ;-) No problem though, it works very well under its own custom wine...

Answer (score 2):

Go to the dash and type in remote, click on the icon that says "desktop sharing" then click the box that says "allow others to view your desktop" on the host computer.

Now from the client computer click on the other icon that says Reminna Remote Desktop Client. Click "Create New Remote Desktop File" in the server box, type in the host computers IP address or host name, then the user name and password. Hit the connect button.

If you are trying to do this from an external computer "away from your home" you will want to make sure you have your external IP address, also you will want to open ports, or if your router supports it, you can put your computer in the DMZ (demilitarized zone) of the routers firewall.

Comment: Note if you try and access a system behind a NAT and a firewall, you need to open the ports first.  You may want to include what those port(s) are.

Comment: Could you edit your question, I've updated the question it's remote access through the internet.